# Mysql error on user create - field doesn't have a default value

Tags: mysql, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am trying to save newly created user with profile. I am using `Yii2-dektrium`. I changed the fields from the `profile` table. Now when I try to save the profile before saving the user I get error because there is still no user. And this is ok. But in this scenario I get this error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'first_name' doesn't have a default value
The SQL being executed was: INSERT INTO `profile` (`user_id`) VALUES (45)
```

The lines of code are these:

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        /** @var Profile $profile */
        $profile = new Profile();

        /** @var User $user */
        $user = \Yii::createObject([
            'class'    => User::class,
            'scenario' => 'create',
        ]);
        $event = $this->getUserEvent($user);

        $this->performAjaxValidation($user);

        $this->trigger(self::EVENT_BEFORE_CREATE, $event);

        if ($profile->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $user->load(\Yii::$app->request->post())) {

            $user->username = $user->email;

            if($user->save()){

                $user = User::findOne(['email' => $user->email]);
                $profile->user_id = $user->id;

                if($profile->save()){

                    $user->addRoles(Yii::$app->request->post('roles'));

                    \Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('success', \Yii::t('user', 'User has been created'));
                    $this->trigger(self::EVENT_AFTER_CREATE, $event);

                    return $this->redirect(['users']);
                }

            }

        }

        return $this->render('create', [
            'account' => $user,
            'profile' => $profile,
            'regionList' => ArrayHelper::getModelsSelect2(new Region()),
        ]);
    }
```

And this is my changed `Profile` model rules:

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['first_name', 'second_name', 'third_name', 'region_id', 'city_id', 'address', 'phone'], 'required'],
            [['region_id', 'city_id'], 'integer'],
            [['first_name', 'second_name', 'third_name', 'address', 'phone'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
        ];
    }
```

After this only the user record is created.
**EDIT**
My table schema:

```
mysql> DESCRIBE `profile`;
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| user_id     | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| first_name  | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| second_name | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| third_name  | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| region_id   | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| city_id     | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| address     | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| phone       | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| image       | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Comment: Edit your question and show the schema of the table. As the error says, you have field(s) that do not allow nulls, and also do not have default values. You can alter the definition of those column to either allow nulls, or add a default value.

Comment: @SloanThrasher You could consider putting your comment as an answer so we can approve it. Also could you provide an example to the default value in the form of a link to the guide

Comment: It looks like a problem with your `Profile` model or form - some fields seems to be missing so this is either problem with missing fields in form or some magic in `Profile` model. How your `Profile` model is defined?

Comment: @MaartenvanMiddelaar I would be glad to provide an answer if the OP will add the schema to their question,

Comment: Will provide as soon as I get to my laptop :)

Comment: The question is edited.

Comment: Do you have any custom properties in this model? Any other non-standard stuff?

Comment: No. Only the rules are changed. The model extends the base `Profile` model of the `dektrium` extension.